# Media Queries for external resource

Tags: css, media-queries

Is it possible to use *Media queries* for external resource?

Example:

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>`

or

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Header.css?v=11"/>`

I would use these resources into Media Queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the attribute media to the "link" tag like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (media feature)" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" /> is correct?